# Is it possible to display output of \G in MySQL in tabular format?

Tags: mysql, shell

I am writing a shell script, where i need to display the output of a MySQL command in columnwise (\G) format.

But seems like \G does not show in table, but just dumps the output. Is it possible to show it in tabular format?

Current output:

```
mysql> select * from ifm.SystemTable \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                     file_id: 1
                     system_name: system1
                      mount_name: /opt/insiteone/fuse-mount
```

What i want:

```
+--------------+--------------------------+
| file_ID      | 1                        |
+-------------+---------------------------+
| system_name  | system1                  |
+----------+------------------------------+
| mount_name   | /opt/insiteone/fuse-mount|               |
+--------------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: Sorry, that is not my answer. \g shows in tabular format but the keys (table headers) are listed per-column, i want it row-wise.

Comment: Please post an example of exactly the output you want, the output you have now, plus the command you are currently using to produce the output you have.

Comment: You may be able to pipe into `column` in the shell, or you may be able to just use `GROUP_CONCAT()` in the query to begin with.

Comment: OK, _what_ does it show in tabular format? You might as well be specific about what you are handling here. I take it `\G` is a shortcut in the MySQL console? (I looked it up - not something I should have to do - and it says "Send command to mysql server, display result vertically.")

Comment: @halfer: I wish to have something like (which i edited my question for and added an example), is it something possible?

Comment: @kingsmasher1 I don't know a way to cause `\G` to produce a literal ASCII table output like a normal statement, but if you have just a few of these queries and know the columns to be produced, you could create it with a `UNION` or with an aggregate.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: No, it's just the output from one table only, so just one query. Can you kindly give me an example to show, how to accomplish that (what you suggested).

Comment: @kingsmasher1 The `UNION` would look like http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e3ca/1 Then when executed _without_ `\G`, MySQL will wrap its normal table output around it. Add aliases or use `--skip-column-names` to omit the table header. MySQL won't draw lines between rows, but will draw between columns